Short horror story about a widow seeking help from a healer who takes fingers as payment
I read this short story in – I think! – a horror anthology. I can't recall the title or the author, and I can't find it in the anthologies I have on my shelves. This what I remember:

A woman is waiting for her husband, a sailor, to return to her and their children. On the day he is due to come home, she instead receives word that he has perished at sea. Widowed, she is left devastated and destitute.
At the foot of their village is a decaying hovel of rotten wood surrounded by an overgrown tangle of thorns. There lives a repellent old woman, who the villagers avoid. They do however seek her out if they become seriously injured or sick, as she has the ability to heal. Her price for this healing is taken in fingers. (I don't think she is ever actually described with the word, "witch", but it's at least heavily implied.) Villagers will return from her hovel missing a finger – but the relatives on whose behalf they've sought help recover without exception.
A plague comes to the village. To begin with, the widow and her children manage to avoid it, but eventually they too get sick. The widow resists resorting to asking the witch for help, but eventually the situation becomes so dire that she is forced to do so.
The widow goes to the witch's hovel. I forget exactly who got sick and how badly, but it's bad enough that the witch demands four (or more?) fingers.
The widow seemingly agrees, but then reveals a concealed weapon (an axe?), and murders the witch.
In the cellar of the hovel, she finds a hideous semi-intelligent creature (a demon, or mutant?). It is this creature that actually had the healing power, fed by the witch on the human fingers she took as payment.
The widow feeds the witch's body to the creature, and makes a pact with it that her family will be healed. (The creature is mute, and it is left ambiguous as to whether it has really understood the bargain.)

I might have misremembered some details. Many thanks in advance for any help!
